# Limit of $f(x)= -x \tanh(x) +\log(2 \cosh (x))$ at $+\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to calculate the limit for $x$ going to $+\infty$ of the following function . The problem originated from a physical model actually

$$f(x)= -x\tanh(x) +\log(2\cosh(x))$$

I get an indeterminate form of the form $-\infty +\infty $ that I don't know how to solve due to the complexity of the functions. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
  &\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left[-x\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}+\log\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)\right]=\\
  &=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left[-x\left(1-2\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}\right)+x+\log\left(1+e^{-2x}\right)\right]=\\
  &=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left[2x\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}+\log\left(1+e^{-2x}\right)\right]=\\
  &=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{2x}{1+e^{2x}}=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} \quad \tanh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$

then

$$-x\tanh(x) +\log(2\cosh(x))=-x\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}+\log(e^x+e^{-x})=$$

$$=-x\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}+\log (e^x)+\log(1+e^{-2x})=-x\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}+x+\log(1+e^{-2x})\to 0$$

indeed

$$\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}=(1-e^{-2x})(1-e^{-2x})+o(e^{-2x})=1-e^{-2x}+o(e^{-2x})$$

and therefore

$$-x\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}+x+\log(1+e^{-2x})=-x+xe^{-2x}+x+\log(1+e^{-2x})+o(xe^{-2x})$$